# Tabs on android 4.0 woes

Tags: java, android, tabs, android-fragments, android-tabs

I'm trying to use tabs on android 2.2 - 4.0. I've extended [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentTabs.html) demo: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentTabs.html with:

```
TabSpec ts = mTabHost.newTabSpec("randomTab");
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(this, FragActiv.class);
ts.setContent(intent);
ts.setIndicator("randomTab");
mTabManager.addTab(ts, FragActiv.class, new Bundle());
```

But I don't know what to add to *onTabChanged*, where all the magic happens in the demo.

*What I need to do is:*
I have a `ListFragment` and when an item is clicked, it should display details in a separate screen on a *small screen/portrait orientation* or, on a *large screen/landscape orientation*, display a fragment with the details on the same screen. Can I work around this with Fragments or should I try to get `FragmentActivities` working properly?

By following this example: [example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentLayoutSupport.html), I was able to instantiate a *FragmentActivity*, but it takes up the whole screen, rather than just the area under the tab menu.

Is there any chance of **using Activities (or FragmentActivities), not Fragments, as contents of the tabs**?

Comment: The problem with saying something like **I've extended this demo** and then providing a link is that you're not showing HOW you extended it. If that demo works but your modifications don't then nobody here can tell you what you've done wrong unless you show your code. As for using Activities as tab content, yes you can do this for all versions of Android. It's deprecated but it still works. If you want a Fragment-based solution then post code and somebody will help. If you want to use a deprecated approach, it will work with Activities - your choice.

Comment: It's in no way different from the sample provided in the link.  I don't want to use anything deprecated. I will edit my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no need of doing what I wanted (using a TabActivity as content of a tab). I've solved the problem by having two containers inside my tabContent, one for the ListView fragment and one for the details fragment. Here is my layout now:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0" />

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:fadingEdge="none" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+android:id/realtabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+android:id/details_container"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Initially, **details_container** is GONE. You can use it as following:

```
        ft.replace(R.id.details_container, detailsFragment);
        FrameLayout detailsLayout = (FrameLayout) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.details_container);
        detailsLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```